# Delphi VCL force menu repaint

Tags: delphi, menu, vcl

I'm setting the main menu font (via Screen.MenuFont) to match the name/size of the font used everywhere else in the program.  But the main menu doesn't refresh with the rest of the form - I have to pass the mouse over each menu item to have it repaint the item in the new font.  How can I force the main menu to repaint on the change?

Answer (score 5):

This is really easy:

Just call the [`DrawMenuBar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawmenubar) function and pass the handle to the form containing the menu:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.MenuFont.Name := 'Arial Black';
  DrawMenuBar(Handle);
end;
```

Comment: Maybe you could move call to `DrawMenuBar` to `procedure CMSysFontChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_SYSFONTCHANGED;` of `TForm1`.

Comment: Great!  Thanks!  And Peter's msg method does work.